# Exclude Functions from where clause in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have used below `query` in one of my `stored procedures`

```
SELECT officeid, rdate
FROM dbo.mytable
Where OfficeID   = OfficeID
  AND YEAR(h.rDate) = @year
  AND MONTH(h.rDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

The above query fails to be a `SARG ( Search Argument)` due to the usage of fuctions `MONTH` and `YEAR` in `Where clause`. This leads `Index scan` during `stored procedure` execution. Is there any way to rewrite the above query to handle the above logic (without `function`)

(P.S:  `rdate` is `datetime` datetype and `@year` is `INT` datatype)

Comment: Are you able to change the parameters? Would be much simpler if you could pass in a date parameter instead of an int. It can still be done of course but much cleaner to pass in a date.

Comment: no actually this stored procedure used in the SSRS report. @year parameter is coming from year combo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Pseudo values..

This below function is SARGABLE(but will be lengthy) ,since  <kbd>[CAST( DATETIME to DATE) is SARAGABLE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable)</kbd>,So Index will be used .

**Example:**

```
Cast(h.rDate as DATE) 
between datefromparts(@year,01,01) 
 and datefromparts(@year,04,30)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use date range comparisons. For example,

```
 SELECT officeid, rdate
    FROM dbo.mytable
    Where OfficeID   = OfficeID
    --Filter by dates that are between January 1st, midnight, inclusive, and
    --May 1st, exclusive, in the desired year
    AND h.rDate >= Convert(DateTime,'1/1/' + Convert(VarChar(4),@year))
    AND h.rDate < Convert(DateTime,'5/1/' + Convert(VarChar(4),@year))
```

Comment: This would be better if you switch the date string to the ANSI compliant yyyy-mm-dd to avoid any localization issues.